# Sending data combined in a form as an array in AJAX/JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, nagios

I need some help to sending my data.

First, the script i've worked for was used as a Mass Acknoledgments Tools for Nagios, hightly inspired from the buyable components for NagiosXI. I've developed it the last and data processing/sending was fully in PHP. Actually, i renove my script, and to do this, i need to use AJAX.

The problems i've encounter is this : below is a screen of my form, the html code to generate it, a screen of the Chrome debugging tool to show you how my data is sent and PHP code for the data retrieve.

[Mass Acknoledgments Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpuJ9.png)

```
    <tr>
   <td class="OK">168VWL1</td>
   <td><a href="javascript:checkAll('host1');">Check all for this hosts</a></td>
   <td class="empty"></td>
   <td class="empty"></td>
   <td class="empty"></td>
   <td class="empty"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td class="empty"></td>
   <td class="critical"><input class="host1 servicecheck" type="checkbox" name="services[]" value="168VWL1::Explorer">Explorer</td>
   <td class="output">Explorer.exe: not running</td>
   <td class="centerd"><input type="checkbox" class="sticky" name="sticky[]" value="168VWL1::Explorer"></td>
   <td class="centerd"><input type="checkbox" class="notify" name="notify[]" value="168VWL1::Explorer"></td>
   <td class="centerd"><input type="checkbox" class="persist" name="persist[]" value="168VWL1::Explorer"></td>
</tr>
```

[Data sending](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aczsn.png)

```
if(isset($_POST['hosts'])){
        $allHosts = json_decode($_POST['hosts']);}

    if(isset($_POST['services'])){
        $allServices = json_decode($_POST['services']);}

    if(isset($_POST['sticky'])){
        $allStickys = json_decode($_POST['sticky']);}

    if(isset($_POST['notify'])){
        $allNotifys = json_decode($_POST['notify']);}

    if(isset($_POST['persistent'])){
        $allPersistents = json_decode($_POST['persistent']);}
```

As you can see,  by doing this way, it's pretty simple to treat my data in PHP, just a call and my array is already generated.

Now, because i use AJAX, i don't know how to sent this by the same way. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Serialize and Post your form data -

```
var formData = $('.campaign-form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: POST_URL_HERE,
    data: formData,
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#form1').serialize()`

to send form data using ajax

Comment: Great way, but for an example, my data is now like this : "services%5B%5D=168VWL1%3A%3AExplorer&services%5B%5D=ESXI1%3A%3AChecking+the+ESXI+Hardware" Is it possible to transform it to JSON ?